Angular Material Version17 Mat Calendar is not getting close on date selection or on backdrop need a refresh to close the picker whole screen is freez

  <div class="ui-lg-3 ui-md-2 ui-g-12 story-section">
        <mat-form-field rds-form-field class="w-90">
          <mat-label rds-form-field-label>End Date</mat-label>
          <input
            #inputEndDate
            matTooltipClass="mat-tool-cust"
            matTooltip="End Date"
            matInput
            placeholder="End Date"
            [formControl]="endDate"
            rds-form-field-input
            [matDatepicker]="picker2"
            trim="blur"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="picker2"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
        <span
          style="margin-top: -16px; display: block"
          *ngIf="invalidEndDt.flag"
        >
          <mat-error rds-form-field-hint-error>
            <i-tabler name="exclamation-circle"></i-tabler>
            {{ invalidEndDt.msg }}
          </mat-error>
        </span>
      </div>

above code snipet i have used not sure why the calendar is not getting close.
I also try close from ts file but it not works

I had the same behavior because of missing BrowserAnimationsModule not imported.
